# Duda con scraping de esta web

Tags: python, scraping

Explico la idea de lo que quiero ejecutar en mi programa. Dada la siguiente web https://www.einforma.com/empresas/Transporte-Y-Almacenamiento/CNAE-5229-Otras-Actividades-Anexas-Al-Transporte/Empresas-42.html lo que se obtiene es una tabla. De dicha tabla me gustaría conseguir por ejemplo el nombre de las empresas de la provincia de sevilla.

Lo que me gustaría hacer es un filtro personalizado. Lo que llevo de código es esto, pero no consigo relacionar el nombre de la empresa con la provincia que quiero...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.einforma.com/empresas/Transporte-Y-Almacenamiento/CNAE-5229-Otras-Actividades-Anexas-Al-Transporte/Empresas-42.html"
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
listaEmpresas = []
#spans = soup.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressRegion'})
trs = soup.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressRegion'})
    empresas = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'itemprop':'name'})
    for span in spans:
        if span.text == "SEVILLA":
            print(span)
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que se me ha ocurrudo que me ha funcionado:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
listaEmpresas = []
listaProvincias = []



c= 1
while c<51:
    url = "https://www.einforma.com/empresas/Transporte-Y-Almacenamiento/CNAE-5229-Otras-Actividades-Anexas-Al-Transporte/Empresas-"+str(c)+".html"
    driver.get(url)

# Parseo el código HTML de la página actual del navegador
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# Busco todos los spans (provincias) con la clase específica
    spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressRegion'})

# Buscamos las empresas con la clase especifica
    empresas = soup.find_all('td',class_="first")

# Con un for recorremos todas las provincias y las almacenamos en listaProvincias
    for i in spans:
        listaProvincias.append(i.text)

# Con un for recorremos todas las empresas y las almacenamos en listaEmpresas
    for empresa in empresas:
        listaEmpresas.append(empresa.text)

    c += 1

# Creamos un diccionario a partir de las 2 listas, empresa y provincia coincidirán por que el orden en el que se ha obtenido es el mismo
diccionario = dict(zip(listaEmpresas,listaProvincias))

#Esto ya es una condición para buscar las empresas de una provincia
for key, values in diccionario.items():
    if values == "CÓRDOBA":
        print(key)
```

Si quitamos el último `for` e imprimimos el contenido del diccionario vemos que tiene cada empresa relaciona con su provincia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]